# AWS WebSocket API gateway must have the same integration for $connect, $disconnect and $default?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I created one AWS websocket api gateway by console, and then I set up routes. I found that AWS keep the integration same for $connect, $disconnect and $default. If I change one of them, then the configuration of the other two will be overridden with the same change.

For example, in $connect, if I click "Integration Request" and choose "Integration type" as "HTTP" (uncheck HTTP proxy) and set "Endpoint URL" as "http://x.y.z.w:8080/connect", then the same setup including "Integration type" and "Endpoint URL" will be applied to $disconnect and $default as well. It is impossible to have different integrations for these 3 routes, which seems very buggy. How to have separate integrations for these pre-defined routes? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. Just delete the routes and add them again, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today: I first created an websocket API Gateway with only a `$connect` route, which worked fine, then I added the `$disconnect` and `$default` routes and never could get them working.

I then deleted the whole stack and re-created it and now everything works fine.

I'm guessing somehow the API Deployment and/or Stage didn't get updated automatically.